# How to call embedded function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-ui

Is it possible to call a variable or function that is inside of the `sort` function within the `stop` function? I need to find the position of `ui.item` while sorting, so I cannot find `ui.item.position()` inside of the stop function.

Also, what type of function is this called? embedded is all I can think of.

**I have tried:**

*`sort().variableName`*

*`event.sort(variableName);`*

*`event.sort().variableName;`*

*`$('.thing').sortable().sort(); // this is the closest I have gotten`*

but these attempts have failed.

```
$('.thing').sortable({
  sort: function(event, ui) {
    var variableName = ui.item.position();
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    // call variableName.left
  }
});
```

Comment: It's called "impossible" because it's scoped to the function it's defined in. You could make it global, in which case you'd have to know whether or not it contained usable information when you called `stop`. You could create a closure around your object passed to `sortable` and enclose `variableName` in that, which solves unintended clobbering or access, but would still have the second problem ("is it even valid right now"). But why do you need it in this fashion? `stop` also gets the `ui` parameter. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am attempting to create a draggable layout similar to gridstack.js using jQuery ui sortable, however, sortable elements will always float to either the right or left, which in my case I need to be able to drop a widget to the left, and drop a widget to the right, with space in between. That is why I need to grab the widgets position while sorting, so that it finds the current position of the widget, where stop will always drop it to the left, which means it would grab the dropped position.

Comment: @DaveNewton Also, I am not using plain drag and drop because draggable elements to not swap out with each other like they do with sortable. There is a way to swap them using a `helper: 'clone'`, but that makes the widgets float left, practically recreating the sortable issue...

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also look at http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you will NOT be able to reach the variable inside the callback.

Consider the following:

```
$(function(){
  var variableName;
  $('.thing').sortable({
    sort: function(event, ui) {
      variableName = ui.item.position();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      // call variableName.left
    }
  });
});
```

Now the variable is registered outside of the function but updated by the function. Now you can call it and get the value.

Hope that helps.